# How to generate row-wise permutations of a 2d Array?

Tags: algorithm, structure, array-algorithms

I recently got this question (paraphrased below) in a practice interview test and it still stumps me:

Given a 2d array A, generate a list of row-wise 1d array permutations from it.

```
A = [
     [1],
     [5, 2],
     [6]
     ]

Answer: [[1, 5, 2, 6], [1, 6, 5, 2], [5, 2, 1, 6], [5, 2, 6, 1], [6, 1, 5, 2], [6, 5, 2, 1]]
```

Explanation of answer: We are permuting on the rows, so it's like generating permutations for [a,b,c] where each of these elements is a 1d array of potentially varying length.

I'm sure the solution involves backtracking, but anytime I try to implement it I end up with a 5+ parameters. I was hoping one of you folks could kindly provide an elegant solution, pseudocode, or explanation.

Comment: generate a permutation of the indexes, and then compute it out

Answer (score 2):

You're really just permuting the row order, and then flattening the matrix for each permutation. Python example:

```py
from itertools import chain, permutations

def flatten(matrix):
    return list(chain(*matrix))

def permute(matrix):
    return [flatten(perm) for perm in permutations(matrix)]
```

With your example:

```py
>>> M = [[1], [5, 2], [6]]
>>> permute(M)
[[1, 5, 2, 6], [1, 6, 5, 2], [5, 2, 1, 6], [5, 2, 6, 1], [6, 1, 5, 2], [6, 5, 2, 1]]
```

In another language, you may have to implement your own helper functions to iterate through permutations (possibly using recursion), and list flattening.

Comment: you cannot really use this in your interview

Comment: @PritamBanerjee I actually would- it shows that you know how to break a problem into smaller, solved problems, rather than inventing a bottom-up solution from scratch. If need be, I'd then write my own implementation of `permutations()` and `chain()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can do it like the following(first get a permutation of all the indexes and then use that to generate the ans):

```
public class RowWisePermutation {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] A = {
                         {1},
                         {5, 2},
                         {6}
        };
        generateRowWisePermutation(A);
    }
    
    public static List<List<Integer>> generateRowWisePermutation(int[][] matrix) {
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        
        List<List<Integer>> indexPermutation = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] indexArr = new int[matrix.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            indexArr[i] = i;
        }
        backtrack(indexArr, temp, indexPermutation);
        
        System.out.println(indexPermutation);
        for(int i = 0; i < indexPermutation.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Integer> indices = indexPermutation.get(i);
            for(Integer index : indices) {
               for(int j = 0; j < matrix[index].length; j++) {
                   row.add(matrix[index][j]);
               }
            }
            ans.add(row);
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
        return ans;
            
    }
    
    private static void backtrack(int[] arr, List<Integer> temp, 
            List<List<Integer>> indexPermutation) {
        
        if(temp.size() == arr.length) {
            indexPermutation.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
            return;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(temp.contains(i)) { continue; }
            temp.add(arr[i]);
            backtrack(arr, temp, indexPermutation);
            temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tyvm, that makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: @polarSyndicate if this works can you please accept the answer